# "Memento rerum conditor..."

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin

I am still working through the *Parvum Officium* and I am having a little trouble parsing the first verse of this hymn. I am pretty confident you people can straighten me out. The verse:

> Memento rerum conditor,
>
> Nostri quod olim corporis
>
> Sacrata ab alvo Virginis
>
> Nascendo formam sumpseris.

I'm fairly confident I understand the first and third lines, but let me attempt translation just in case I do not. First:

> Remember! Creator of [the] things!

Third:

> From the holy womb of [the] Virgin

Now, (gulp) the second. I think *nostri* and *corporis* are linked together to mean *of our body* and that *quod olim* is a kind of parenthetical, subordinate adjectival clause:

> ..., that at that time, of our body...

Perhaps that is right. Perhaps not.

I have even less to work with in the fourth line, because I do not really understand the gerundive *nascendo*.  I suspect that the accusative *formam* is linked to the *nostri ... corporis* in the second line.

So, it seems my questions are:

- Are any of my above assertions incorrect?
- How does *nascendo* operate in this text?

I have an English translation in hand, but given that this is a hymn and subject to rhyme and meter constraints, I do not expect it to follow very rigidly, and I really want to understand the Latin on its own terms. Here is the translation for reference:

> Remember, O Creator Lord!
>
> That in the Virgin's sacred womb
>
> thou wast conceived, and of her flesh
>
> Didst our mortality assume.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my understanding of the verse. (Note: I'm only a beginner with Latin.)

> Remember (*Memento*), O founder/maker (*conditor*) of things (*rerum*), that (*quod*) once (*olim*), you took (*sumpserīs*) the form (*formam*) of our (*nostri*) body (*corporis*) by being born (*nascendo*) from (*ab*) the sanctified (*sacratā*) womb (*alvo*) of a virgin (*virginis*).

### Nascendo / gerund vs. gerundive

**Nascendo** here is a gerund, not a gerundive. That is, it's functioning as a noun, not an adjective modifying some other noun. It's in the ablative case to mean that it's *by* being born that the Maker takes on human form.

**Gerund**

A gerund in Latin is a verb functioning substantively, i.e., as a noun, in an oblique case. In the ablative case, **nascendo** means **by being born**. Notice that English has the same construction, also called "gerund", in which a verb plays the role of a noun. "Being born happens early in a person's life." A gerund has the active voice. For example, in:

> Desine fata deum flecti sperare **precando**. [Aeneid, 6.376]
>   = Stop hoping to bend the will of the gods **by praying**.

the person doing the praying is Aeneas, i.e., the person being addressed. Since **nascor** is a deponent verb, **nascendo** takes an active meaning even though the verb is basically passive (or at least we think of it that way in English: **to be born**, **being born**).

**Gerundive**

The gerundive has the same form as the gerund, but a gerundive is a participle, i.e. a verb functioning as an adjective. For example, in:

> Karthago **delenda** est.
>   = Carthage must be **destroyed**.

**delenda** is an adjective modifying **Karthago**. It changes case to agree with the noun that it modifies, like this:

> Ceterum censeo Karthaginem **delendam** esse.
>   = And lastly, I say that Carthage must be **destroyed**.

Unlike the gerund, the gerundive is passive. Cato isn't recommending that Carthage do some destroying; he's recommending that Carthage *be* destroyed. In the case of **nascendo**, though, since **nascor** is deponent and intransitive, I'm not sure there's any difference in meaning between understanding it actively or passively.

Since there's no noun in the verse for a gerundive **nascendo** to modify, it seems unlikely that it's meant as a gerundive. It might cause some confusion that in Latin, an adjective can function substantively, and that applies to gerundives, too. For example, **mutatis mutandis**, "the necessary changes having been made," or literally, "the things that need to be changed, having been changed." Without a noun to modify, the gerundive means "things that are to be *X*'ed." However, in the verse, I don't think it would make sense to understand **nascendo** that way; then it would mean "by someone who is to be born".

By the way, I did not think any of the above through when reading the sentence. Happily, even with my fairly meager experience reading Latin, I understood it simply by analogy with sentences like the one above ending in **precando**.
The text below mentions a couple other possibilities for how to understand **nascendo** in this context.

### Other bits and pieces

I think you are right that **nostri corporis** modifies **formam**. **Nostri corporis** might seem an awfully long distance from the noun that it modifies. In between them there is another genitive, even! Possibly that long distance is actually intentional bracketing of the enclosing clause rather than a compromise with meter. Seen that way, enclosing **sacrata ab alvo Virginis nascendo** inside **nostri corporis formam** might even be a way to indicate how the causal relation between the two phrases is intended to be understood.

I think of **olim** as meaning something similar to English "once upon a time" or "long ago", but not limited to the past, so it can also mean "someday", and not limited to children's stories, so it can also mean "once" or "one time", as in "Once, I adopted a stray cat."

Something I'm not completely sure of is **sumpseris**. With a short *i*, **sumpserĭs**, it's future perfect: "Keep in mind that one day, you will have taken the form…" With a long *i*, **sumpserīs**, it's perfect subjunctive: "Remember that once, you took the form…" I figure that the past tense makes more sense here, but the subjunctive mood seems strange because the event is already accomplished fact. Possibly imperative **memini** customarily governs a subjunctive verb even when referring to known fact; someone with better knowledge of Latin will have to clarify that. (See [new question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1179/118) about this.)

Alas, I'm pretty sure that vowel quantity plays no role in medieval rhyme, so I don't think that we can use the short vowels of **corporĭs** and **virginĭs** to infer the quantity of the last vowel in **sumpseris**.

Regarding gerund vs. gerundive, perhaps one could argue that **nascendo** modifies an implied noun **te**, so the meaning is "by you who are to be born". I don't think this makes sense with either reading of **sumpseris**, though. As **sumpserĭs**: "Remember that thou took'st human form by thee who art to be born…" As **sumpserīs**: "Keep in mind that thou wilt have taken human form by  thee who art to be born…"

### Ablative of time?

I found a few English translations that treat **nascendo** as referring not to the means but the time of the Maker's taking human form. The [*Manual of Devout Prayers*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kx1lAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA84&dq=%22memento+rerum+conditor%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpw6jw5OvNAhWMTSYKHexGBPc4FBC7BQg0MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22memento%20rerum%20conditor%22&f=false) (1688), p. 84, has:

> Divine Creator, bear in mind,
>   That thou, of our corporeal kind,
>   The form assumedst heretofore,
>   When thee a Sacred Virgin bore.

Unless **nascendo** is commonly used to refer to *when* someone was born, analogous to "et requievit **die septimo**", I think it needs a preposition or adverb to refer only to the time of the birth, but I thought I should mention this. The grammar might mark an important point of theology: that the Maker got human form *from* Mary's womb, indicated by *ab.* I think that in ordinary Latin grammar, this means that the *act* that transferred the form was the birth—hence the need for an ablative gerund.

Comment: I think your translation is correct. A couple of notes: (1) already in Classical Latin there is confusion between -erĭs and -erīs in the pf. subj., so even if vowel quantity mattered for medieval verse (which it doesn't) that might not tell us anything. (2) The syntax here is non-Classical. CL would use an indirect statement construction after *memento*, rather than *quod* + subj. as here. (I'm assuming *sumpseris* is subj. because fut. pf. makes no sense.) Maybe someone who knows more about Ecclesiastical Latin can tell us if this construction is regular.

Comment: @TKR, would the classical analogue of *memento quod sumpseris* be *memento te sumpsisse*?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Yes, I believe so.

Comment: @Joonaslimavirta -- medieval and ecclesiastical Latin often 'introduce' indirect speech with a *quod*, *quia*, or *quoniam* (where *quia* and *quoniam* sometimes indicate the indirect speech is directly related speech). When indirect speech is constructed this way, the mood of the (as it were) 'main verb of the indirect speech clause' is often indicative (while subordinate clauses therein are usually still subjuntive).  Needless to say, these sorts of 'object clauses' with *quod*, etc., can mess up the sequence of tenses.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to produce this answer. How do you know nascendo is a gerund and not a gerundive? (I was following this: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/nascendus#Latin)

Comment: @DavidCharles I just expanded the answer to explain why I was led to think **nascendo** is a gerund here and not a gerundive. Notice also that **nascendo** is listed here under "gerund": https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nascor#Inflection The gerundive is also listed there, but the ablative only implicitly: it's a form of the future participle **nascendus**.

Comment: @jon, in this case the main verb of the indirect speech is *sumpseris*, which must be perfect subjunctive -- any thoughts on why it's subjunctive rather than indicative?

Comment: @TKR -- In Collins, ed., *A Primer of Ecclesiastical Latin* (Washington, 1985), § 135, it says that the normal situation is the 'retained indicative', but that *quod*, *quia*, and *quoniam* may be followed by the subjunctive when the clause 'emphasizes the grammatical subordination of the indirect statement'. (Compare Greek's [`ὅτι`](http://biblehub.com/greek/3754.htm).)  ... Now, is that what is 'really' going on here, or are there metrical reasons at play that helped push us to the subjunctive ..?

Comment: @jon I've been wondering if the subjunctive was called upon just to make a rhyme! One other hypothesis: a subjunctive in **memento quod …** might "agree" with holding something in your mind; the subjunctive might psychologically place the remembered fact at a distance. I haven't checked anything to confirm or refute this, though.

Comment: @jon -- Interesting, thanks. Not sure what to make of "emphasizes the grammatical subordination". Very likely you're right that the subjunctive here is metri (or rimae) causa.

Comment: @TKR -- Indeed. The two (fake) examples given are not very enlightening. (1) *Invenimus quod Paulus Romam iam isset.* (2) *Credunt quia Christus sit Dominus.* However, you will find the Vulgate full of indirect discourse introduced by those three words, so there would be plenty of examples to work your way through.

Comment: @BenKovitz -- Yes, I wondered the very same thing about the rhyme....

Comment: One need not look far into the Vulgate to find an example of this use of the subjunctive: "et vidit Deus lucem quod *esset* bona et divisit lucem ac tenebras".

Comment: @DavidCharles I've asked a [new question](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1179/118) specifically about the use of subjunctive mood here.