# indicative vs subjunctive tenses

Tags: grammar-identification

What is a difference between indicative and subjunctive in Latin? For example:

1. ego sum
2. ego sim

Context: I am a Latin self-learner. I am trying to get an idea about its tenses.

Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated to the question itself: It appears that you have created two accounts. Please consider registering your account and [merging the two together following these instructions](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This site is much more flexible for a registered user, especially with the reputation and subsequent privileges you have earned.

Comment: I have only one account. The other posts are associated with the same email address, but there it is not confirmed. Could we please start to talk about the initial question?

Comment: Are you using a textbook? What does the book say? Have you looked into this at all first and want clarification? There are also plenty of questions here before that talk about the subjunctive, like [this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12814/subjunctive-mood-in-latin), [this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/10849/subjunctive-mood-in-comparison/10890#10890), and [this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5675/when-to-use-cum-subjunctive-and-when-cum-indicative). Please read them over first and then we can help with any specific questions you might have.

Comment: If you have any questions about how this works, feel free to inquire in our chatroom.

Comment: @Jan As I pointed out, merging the two accounts has benefits to you: You get improved privileges and you can accept and vote on answers. My only point was to help. // We can start talking about the initial question, but you should start. Please take a look at the other questions and use the site's search tool to learn what's already been explained on the site. Elaborating on what is clear and what is still confusing after reading related posts makes for a good question.