# Non obstante eo

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin

What is the translation of "non obstante eo" in the context of this sentence? Also, is the rest of my translation accurate?

This is the original text:

> De Gentilibus dicitur passim, quod rejectis Iudaeis ipsi electi a Deo, id est, vocati sint ad obediendum Evangelio et sic ad beneficia Evangelio promissa consequendum ea ratione ac via, quae Evangelio continetur ac praescribitur: siue denique vocationi jam factae refragentur; quo sensu diligi adhuc Iudaei increduli dicuntur secundum electionem Rom 11 & passim populus Israeliticus non obstante eo, quod rebellione et contumacia sua Deum subinde fatigaret, electus tamen Dei populus passim in V.T. vocatur.

And this is my translation:

> It is said everywhere concerning the Gentiles that with the Jews having been rejected, they themselves have been chosen by God, that is, they have been called to obedience to the Gospel and thus to attaining the benefits promised in the Gospel by that manner and way which is contained and prescribed in the Gospel: on the other hand, they are now resistant to the calling, in which sense the incredulous Jews are still said to be loved "concerning election" and the Israelite people "non obstante eo," their vexation of God again and again by their rebellion and contumacy, is everywhere called the people of God in the Old Testament.

Answer (score 1):

I would analyse *non obstante eo quod* as “in spite of the fact that …, the fact that … notwithstanding” etc. (literally: “with it not hindering that …,” i.e., it is an ablativus absolutus). And why the subjunctive? I would say it is another case of the dreaded [quod cum coniunctivo](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/memento-quod-subjunctive).

I think you got the first part right but started stumbling at *siue denique*, which means “even if.” The whole second part of the sentence means:

> … [the gentiles are called] even if they resist the calling, already made (1); in the same sense as the infidel Jews are still said to be chosen (2), according to the election (3), Romans 11, and far and wide the people of Israel, even though they tired God again and again with their rebellion and defiance, are still called God's chosen people everywhere in the Old Testament.

Remarks:

1. I do not quite understand what the author means by *jam factae* here, it agrees with *vocationi* (dat. sing.)
2. I believe *diligere* means the same as *deligere* here; if the author intends to express something by the different use of *diligere* here and *eligere* later, it escapes me
3. Very likely an allusion to the same wording *secundum electionem* in [Romanos 11,5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%2011&version=VULGATE): *Sic ergo et in hoc tempore reliquiae secundum electionem gratiae salvae factae sunt.*

Comment: I think *vocationi jam factae* means "to a calling already made".